# Search for file and return filename? need H.e.l.p

Tags: string, file

Good day to all,

Ok guys this is the scenario... i need to search a directory to see if a file exists. example 35325553AW.flpart, i'm using this code to search for the existance of the file using part of the name:

Dim FileLocation As DirectoryInfo = _
 New DirectoryInfo("C:\Folder\Subfolder\Data\Input\")

Dim fi As FileInfo() = FileLocation.GetFiles("*35325553*.flpart")

at the end it works, because i have one files in the directory folder and when i check "fi" variable it tells me that the value is fi {Lenght=1}.

Now here comes the main question....

Can someone help me with the code to return the name of the existing file as string so i can show it in a combobox.

if i search 35325553 i need to show in the combobox 35325553AW as this is how it is the file named only removing the extension, hope this is clear enough and you can help me.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Good day, i finally found the way to do it, reading over the internet, this is how i was able to do it.

Hope it helps somebody esle,

```
For Each foundflpart In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
        "Directory",
        FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly,
        "*35325553*.flpart") ' This returns: /Directory/35325553aw.flpart as string

        oestring = Replace(foundflpart, "Directory", "") ' This leaves only 35325553aw.flpart
        oestring = Replace(oestring, ".flpart", "") ' This leaves only 35325553aw
        oestring = oestring.ToUpper 'and his changes any character to uppercase returning 35325553AW
```

Best regards